# How to deploy & configure thinking sphnix on production server

Tags: capistrano, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, ruby-on-rails-5.2

i have tried install & configure thinking sphinx on local host & its working fine. When i tried to install on production server i am confuse with how to configure thinking sphinx on server.

here is the configure file development.sphinx.conf

```
indexer
{
}

searchd
{

  listen = 127.0.0.1:9306:mysql41
  log = /home/log/development.searchd.log
  query_log = /home/log/development.searchd.query.log
  pid_file = /home/log/development.sphinx.pid
  workers = threads
  binlog_path = /tmp/binlog/development
}

index product_core
{
  type = rt
  path = /db/sphinx/development/product_core
  docinfo = extern
  rt_field = sphinx_internal_class_name
  rt_field = name
  rt_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
  rt_attr_uint = company_id
  rt_attr_bigint = sphinx_internal_id
  rt_attr_string = sphinx_internal_class
  rt_attr_string = name_sort
}

index product
{
  type = distributed
  local = product_core
}
```

Anyone please guide me configure thinking sphinx on production server

Comment: Hi Vishu - have you followed the documentation for setting up production paths for the configuration and index files? https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v4/deployment.html#basics - and if so, what problems are you seeing?

Comment: yes i followed this documentation but when i try to run ts:configure or ts:index ,it shows the error "rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'ts:configure' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
"

Comment: Does that error appear when you run the command directly in the production environment? Do other tasks (such as `db:migrate`) work fine?

Comment: yes, its working fine . i have run some tasks & working fine

Comment: And `thinking-sphinx` is available for all environments in your Gemfile?

Comment: yes . available for all environments .

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Which version of Thinking Sphinx are you using? Does `rake --tasks` show any Thinking Sphinx tasks? Can you share the entire output of running `rake ts:configure` in your question?